# как задать цвет числу в С#?

Tags: c#

Есть код, который переводит все в двоичный код. Теперь мне нужно задать числу 1 - черный цвет, а 0 - белый цвет. Задав это, я хочу получать картинку с пикселями. 
Я пишу шифратор и идея такая: человек вводит свое предложение, нажимает кнопку "зашифровать", появляется картинка с черно-белыми пикселями. 
Как все это сделать?

Comment: С чем конкретно у вас проблема?

Comment: Не понимаю, как присвоить что-то числу. Ну 1 - это что-то, а 0 - это что-то другое. Допустим, я не хочу пиксели рисовать, а просто хочу реализовать замену единицы на букву в. Вот как это, например, реализовать? Не могу же просто так присвоить 1 "в"

Comment: Ничего не понятно, формулируйте яснее. Что значит присвоить что-то числу? Присвоить что-то числу невозможно

Comment: Подождите, я правильно понял? То есть единица - это, например, "в", а ноль - это, например, "г". Все состоит из нулей и единиц. Таким образом, фраза состоит только из букв "в" и "г". Так? Я всегда чувствовал, что у нас в алфавите слишком много букв.

Comment: Да,  Igor , вы правы. Это я и пытаюсь сделать сейчас. В будущем заменю буквы на пиксели. Пока мне нужно понять, как определить замену

Comment: С помощью `string.Replace`, например

Comment: спасибо. а как теперь задать цвет? суть вопроса ,  вы, видимо, поняли

Comment: ... хотя это и было нелегко

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как задать цвет числу?

Формальный ответ на этот вопрос будет следующим:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

dict.Add(1, "черный");
dict.Add(0, "белый");
```

Здесь мы задали числу 1 черный цвет, а числу 0 - белый. Логично?

---

Ладно, ладно, реализуем то, о чем речь в комментариях.

```
var random = new Random();
var number = random.Next();

var result = Convert.ToString(number, 2);
result = result.Replace('1', 'b').Replace('0', 'r');

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Сгенерировали случайное число, преобразовали его в двоичный вид, заменили единицы и нули на определенные символы. Число зашифровано. Правильно?

---

О, оказывается картинка нужна.

Используем `System.Drawing.Bitmap`.

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(32, 1);

for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    if ((number & (1 << i)) != 0)
        bitmap.SetPixel(i, 0, Color.White);
    else
        bitmap.SetPixel(i, 0, Color.Black);
}

bitmap.Save("pic.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Для 32-битного числа создаем изображение размером 32x1.

В цикле определяем битовыми операциями значение каждого бита и задаем цвет соответствующему пикселю.

Предупреждение: метод `SetPixel` работает очень медленно, поэтому его не стоит использовать при работе с большими изображениями. Вместо него используйте LockBits (поиск в помощь).

Answer (score 2):

Откомментировать я пока не могу.

Берешь двоичный код и последовательно выделяешь каждую 1 или 0 (можно сделать при помощи логических операций и сдвигов) , потом полученный результат сравниваешь 1 или 0 и выводишь цветной пиксель и т.д. Метод вывод цвета зависит от типа приложения.